# Read icc-profile with imagemagick thru exec in php

Tags: php, imagemagick, exec, color-profile, color-management

I am trying to use the imagemagick **identify -format** to read what icc-profile an image has. I use php on a Windows server.

I use the following command:

```
identify -format "%[profile:icc]" image.jpg > file.txt
```

If I run it in **command-line** it works and saves the icc-profile name to the file.txt.

But when I try to do the same thing in php with exec I get an empty file:

```
exec('identify -format "%[profile:icc]" image.jpg > file.txt');
```

I have tried **-format** with other attributes that work, like:

```
exec('identify -format "%[size]" image.jpg > file.txt');
```

Comment: Are you sure php calls the same version of ImageMagick? profile:icc has only been available since 6.8.7.2.

Comment: That did the trick. Had not rebooted after I changed the paths, thanks!